# Много If-ов - нормально?

Tags: php

Написал порядка полусотни if-ов для проверки и присваивания существования значений переменным вида

```
if (!$key1) $var1 = "нет данных";
else var1 = "Значение_1";
if (!$key2) $var1 = "нет данных";
else var2 = "Значение_2";

...

if (!$keу50) $var50 = "нет данных";
else var50 = "Значение50";
```

Т.е по умолчанию всем переменным присваивается значение `"нет данных"`

Насколько такие конструкции некрасивы (говнокод?) и как правильнее делать?

PS. `keyN` предварительно достаю из базы, а `varN` в дальнейшем уходит в массив.

**Добавка**:
Прошу прощения, я не учел как оказалось важный момент:

Все имена переменных - как ключей, так и значений - уникальны и не поддаются цифровой "маркировкой".  В реальности эти имена типа
`$saper_resolution_key`, `$desar_price_key`, `$insment_rate_var` и тп. А значения к тому же ещё и не одинакового формата - где-то просто текст, где-то конкатенация с переменными, причём в разном порядке и наборах.
Поэтому формирование предварительного массива мне кажется ещё более проблемно, а последующая его обработка и вовсе запутает.

И по просьбам из коментариев привожу кусочек реального кода

```
if (rwmb_meta('deres-reser','',$post_id)==0)  $deres_reser_var = "Нет";
else $deres_reser_var = "Да";

if (!rwmb_meta('ssumnal-minsumm','',$post_id)) $ssumnal_minsumm_var = "нет данных";
else $ssumnal_minsumm_var = rwmb_meta('ssumnal-minsumm','',$post_id)." руб";

if (!rwmb_meta('sader-age','',$post_id)) $sader_age_var = "нет данных"; 
else $sader_age_var = "От".rwmb_meta('sader-age','',$post_id)." лет";

if (!rwmb_meta('fasan-servise','',$post_id)) $fasan_servise_var = "нет данных";
else $fasan_servise_var = rwmb_meta('fasan-servise','',$post_id);
```

тут функция `rwmb_meta('fasan-servise','',$post_id))` получает из базы значения поля с именем `fasan-servise`

А в дальнейшем из этих данных я составлю массив и передаю его в обработку

```
$arr = array ( $deres_reser_key => $deres_reser_var, $ssumnal_minsumm_key => $ssumnal_minsumm_var , $sader_age_key => $sader_age_var, $fasan_servise_key => $fasan_servise_var);
```

*(В этом массиве на переменные ключей не обращайте внимания - в данном случае они не играют роль и я упростил для понимания логики их именований)*

Comment: Вместо кучи `if`'ов можно использовать цикл и массивы. Только нужно предварительно значения `%key\d+` положить в массив, чтобы после его в цикле перебрать и заполнить значения `$var\d+` в другом списке

Comment: «Написал порядка полусотни if» — когда, скажем, четвертый писали, не подумали, что что-то не так делаете?

Comment: *а varN в дальнейшем уходит в массив* Чё б им сразу-то не родиться массивом, а? *keyN предварительно достаю из базы* Если имена именно такие - то они прекрасно итерируются в цикле.

Comment: @gil9red проблема в том, что имена переменных уникальны, цифровые суффиксы не применяются

Comment: @sto вы давайте нормально описание приведите. как из базы получаете, и какие значения. если без суффиксов, то напишите как есть

Comment: Вопрос в том, зачем вам переменным присваивать значение "нет данных" если это будет очевидно в момент отображения ?

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Akina я обновил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле есть не мало вариантов реализции подобного кода.
Для приведенного в примере кода лучше использовать тернарный оператор:

```
$var1 = $key1 ? 'Значение1' : 'нет данных';
$var2 = $key2 ? 'Значение2' : 'нет данных';
$var3 = $key3 ? 'Значение3' : 'нет данных';
$var50 = $key50 ? 'Значение50' : 'нет данных';
```

Второй вариант, если уместно, положить всё в массив и обойти его циклом:

```
$keysArray = [$key1, $key2, $key3, $key50];

$valuesArray = [];
$i = 1;

foreach ($keysArray as $key) {
    $valuesArray[] = $key ? 'Значение' . $i++ : 'нет данных';
}
```

В общем, способов избавиться от if-else достаточно.

Comment: спс и прошу прощения.  я обновил вопрос

Comment: Смотрите в комментах ниже вариант с использованием функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Функция вернет $value в случае успеха и $failValue - неудачи    
function getValue($key, $value, $failValue='нет данных') {
    return $key? $value: $failValue;
}

$var1 = getValue($key1, 'значение 1')
$var2 = getValue($key2, 'значение 2')
$var3 = getValue($key3, 'значение 3')
```

Да, если у вас много значений, то лучше использовать массивы для результата, ключей, правильных значений и неправильных, по необходимости

Comment: спс и прошу прощения.  я обновил вопрос